# I can't assign value to object in list c++

Tags: c++, object, setter

I have struct Point, it contains setters for x and y:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    Point(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    Point& operator=(Point other) {
        swap(x, other.x);
        swap(y, other.y);
        return *this;
    }

    void setX(int _) { x = _; }

    void setY(int _) { y = _; }

};
```

Also I have Element for bidirectional list, its data is Point:

```
struct Element {
    Point data;
    Element *left;
    Element *right;

    Element(Point data) {
        this->data = data;
        left = right = this;
    }

};
```

And also I created List structure, Point get(int i) returns Point I want to change:

```
struct List {
    Element *first;
    Element *last;
    int length;

    List() {
        first = last = nullptr;
        length = 0;
    }

    Point add(Point data) {
        Element *e = new Element(data);
        length++;
        if (!last) {
            first = last = e;
            return data;
        }
        e->left = last;
        last = last->right = e;
        return data;
    }

    Point get(int i) {
        if (i >= length && i<0) return Point();
        Element *t = first;
        while(i--) t = t->right;
        return t->data;
    }

};
```

Then in main I create List, I add Point to this list and then I try to change x and y values, but they don't change:

```
int main() {
    ....
    List snake;
    snake.add(Point(3,4));
    cout << snake.get(0).x << " " << snake.get(0).y << endl;
    snake.get(0).setX(99);
    snake.get(0).setY(99);
    cout << snake.get(0).x << " " << snake.get(0).y << endl;
    .....
}
```

Please, help! Why don't x and y values change and how to fix it?

Comment: Why does `=` swap?

Comment: "I try to change x and y values, but they don't change:" what do you mean ? Your code has no output. How do you know the values didn't change?

Comment: I print check x and y with this line:
cout << snake.get(0).x << " " << snake.get(0).y << endl;

Comment: You need to return the `Point` by reference in `get`. Something like `Point& get(int i) { ... }`

Comment: you should include that line in the code you posted. Not showing us the same code you are looking at just makes things more complicated. The code you posted has actually no observable effects

Comment: Thank you, super!

Comment: Ok, I'll include this line!

Comment: Note: your `Point` is nearly a textbook example of a quasi-class. http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method:

```
Point get(int i) {
    if (i >= length && i<0) return Point();
    Element *t = first;
    while(i--) t = t->right;
    return t->data;
}
```

returns a `Point` by value. The object returned is not the object in the list. Hence here:

```
snake.get(0).setX(99);
```

You do `setX(99)` of a `Point`, but that `Point` is the temporary object returned from `get`. You probably want to return a reference instead. However, then you need to find a different solution for `if (i >= length && i<0) return Point();`, ie the case when the index is out of bounds, because you cannot return a reference to a local variable. You can either throw an exception or simply assume that the passed index is a valid one. Change it to:

```
Point& get(int i) {
   //^  return reference
    //if (i >= length && i<0) return Point();
  //^^ DO NOT return a reference to  ^^ local object !!!
    Element *t = first;
    while(i--) t = t->right;
    return t->data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I just changed Point get(int i) signature to Point& get(int i)

Comment: @help no. Thats not good. As I wrote, you shall not return a reference to a local object. At the very least you need to remove the line: `if (i >= length && i<0) return Point();`. Or find another way to handle invalid indices

Comment: Ok, I removed this line. I'll handle invalid indices before calling get then.

Comment: OP's `operator=` uses the copy&swap idiom. It's completely unnecessary in this case, but the form itself is not unusual.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have to admit, I just took it from a comment without thinking much about it, I will remove the PS